# OnetoOnefield in django form not working.

Tags: python, django, forms, one-to-one

I have created UserForm that has OnetoOnefield of User built-in Form.

UserForm has description,city,website,phone,image

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):

    description = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Description','default':"{{user.userprofile.description}}"}), required=False,
        max_length=100)
    city = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'City:'}), required=False,
        max_length=70)
    website = forms.URLField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Website:'}), required=False,
        max_length=100)
    phone = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Phone:'}), required=False,
        max_length=10)
    image = forms.ImageField(label='Select a profile picture')

    class Meta():
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['description','city','website','phone','image']
```

views.py

```
def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            messages.success(request,"description added successfully")
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
        else:
            messages.error(request,"")



    else:
        form = UserForm()
    return render(request, 'edit_profile.html', {'form': form})
```

models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='No description field')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Location not added')
    website = models.URLField(default='', blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='',blank= True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/profile/%Y%/%m/%d', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


def create_profile(sender,**kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user = kwargs['instance'])

post_save.connect(create_profile,sender=User)
```

admin.py

```
admin.site.register(UserProfile)
```

The problem is, whenever i try to enter values in form and click submit it doesn't to anything it refreshes form and says the field is required at image field. any solution please? thanks
P.S values can be stored through admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

File contents are in `request.FILES`. Just instantiate the form like:

```
form = UserForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

Comment: IntegrityError at /account/profile/edit_profile
NOT NULL constraint failed: account_userprofile.user_id